# E716: Key not present in dictionary: "3"

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, dictionary

I have this global at the top of my `.vimrc`:

```
let DevEnv = { 'enabled' : 0, 'open_dirs' : 0, 'term_bufnr' : 0 }
```

One of my `.vimrc` functions calls:

```
exec 'bd! ' . g:DevEnv.term_bufnr
```

Note that `g:DevEnv.term_bufnr` has been updated to a non-zero value at one point by another function so that it contains a valid buffer number.

This line works as intended and closes the buffer which is saved at `g:DevEnv.term_bufnr`, BUT, when I run `:echo errmsg`, I get the aforementioned error. Commenting out this line fixes it. Why am I getting this error if everything works as intended? Have I misused something?

Also, this only seems to show that message if I run `bd!`. Using `echo` does not display it.

I tried passing `g:DevEnv.term_bufnr` through a proxy by doing:

```
let asd = g:DevEnv.term_bufnr
exec 'bd! ' . asd
```

Which, also gave the error after the second line was executed. I can only guess it has something to do with the internal workings of `bdelete`.

Comment: In your example, you don't initialize `DevEnv` as a global, could that be the problem?

Comment: It's in the top of my `.vimrc`, is that not the same?

Comment: I don't think so!

Comment: I tried it, and it made no difference.

Comment: Try using `g:DevEnv['term_bufnr']` or `'bd! ' .. g:DevEnv.term_bufnr` with `:scriptversion 2` if your Vim is new enough. I think you may be running in to the "`.` is ambiguous problem". See `:help scriptversion-2`.

Comment: @MartinTournoij, I've applied all those suggestions at once and still get this message. I must also reiterate that the only way I know there is an error is because I print `errmsg`, as I get no prompt after the command, and it executes as it should.

Comment: Are you sure this `bd` is the culprit? You could `echom` messages before and after just to make sure.

Comment: Yes, it echoes without problem.

Comment: I don't know then  It would help if you could add a more complete example: something I can copy/paste in my vimrc to try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: You could copy paste the two lines at the start of the question and then using `:echo errmsg` and it should give you the same output, only with zero instead of 3.